# 301 redirect behavior in a drupal system

Tags: redirects, drupal

I am migrating an older site to a newer one which is using Drupal. As part of this I am trying to setup some 301 redirects to the new pages but I am getting some unexpected behavior. I added the following line to my .htaccess file:

```
redirect 301 /redirect.html http://www.example.com/newpage
```

Unfortunately, what happens is that I get taken to:

```
http://www.example.com/newpage?q=redirect.html
```

Which of course doesn't load correctly. Any thoughts?

Comment: I have a question about your question. Did clean urls configure correctly?

Comment: Clean urls did configure correctly.

Comment: The above directive alone would not have resulted in the redirect stated, so it's likely there was a conflict. Particularly since Drupal uses mod_rewrite and the above is a mod_alias directive. You should never mix redirects from both modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after a bit of searching, I found the answer [here](http://drupal.org/node/38960). It is similar to danlefree's but slightly diffrent.

```
<IFModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    # custom redirects

    RewriteRule ^redirect\.html$ http://www.mysite.com/newpage [R=301,L]

    # end custom redirects

    ...
</IFModule>
```

This seems to get the job done.

Comment: Ditto! But I still think you should look at my answer ;)

Comment: Instead of hacking around at the Apache level, consider using an appropriate Drupal module - it gives you a lot more power and flexibility.

Answer (score 2):

Forget `.htaccess.` Use the [global redirect](http://drupal.org/project/globalredirect). It gives you the following:

1. Checks the current URL for an alias and does a 301 redirect to it if it is not being used.
2. Checks the current URL for a trailing slash, removes it if present and repeats check 1 with the new request.
3. Checks access to the URL. If the user does not have access to the path, then no redirects are done. This helps avoid exposing private aliased node's.

It simplifies migration of your website slightly, and probably most important, it makes it simple to look up exactly what is being redirected where. (as there is a user interface for it)

**Bonus** (*imagine clippy popping up here*)

You seem to be creating something similar to [clean URLs](http://drupal.org/node/15365). I think you might be interested in [pathauto](http://drupal.org/handbook/modules/pathauto).

Comment: Good suggestion - I was going to recommend [Path Redirect](http://drupal.org/project/path_redirect) for similar reasons.

Comment: I looked into this and it conflicted with the Gallery module we had installed.

Answer (score 0):

Your other rewrite rules are interfering.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/redirect\.html$ http://www.mysite.com/newpage [L,R=301]

# ... existing rewrites
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: This would have worked in the server config. However, in per-directory .htaccess files the directory-prefix is removed from the URL-path that matches against the `RewriteRule` _pattern_. So, the slash (`/`) should simply be removed from `^/redirect\.html$` to become `^redirect\.html$`.

Answer (score 0):

We used to [Path redirect module](https://drupal.org/project/path_redirect) for that purpose.  It can't handle all powerful things that Mod_rewrite can, but it's done a really nice job for us at preserving old URLs.